# Dom0 not forwarding to DomU

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, xen, debian-wheezy

## The situation:

### DomU: Debian SID

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address x.x.x.55
 gateway x.x.x.49
 netmask 255.255.255.255
 pointopoint x.x.x.49
```

Ping DomU -> x.x.x.49 (aka Dom0)

```
PING x.x.x.49 (x.x.x.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from x.x.x.49: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
```

Ping DomU -> 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
34 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 33263ms
```

tcpdump -Kn

```
21:03:30.316328 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4904, seq 3, length 64
21:03:31.324344 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4904, seq 4, length 64
21:03:32.332338 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4904, seq 5, length 64
21:03:33.340323 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4904, seq 6, length 64
21:03:34.348343 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4904, seq 7, length 64
```

### Dom0: Debian Wheezy with Xen 4.1

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address x.x.x.49
 gateway x.x.x.33
 netmask 255.255.255.255
 pointopoint x.x.x.33
```

sysctl -a

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.vif1/0.proxy_arp = 1
```

iptables -L -n *(rules automatically added by vif-route)*

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     all  --  x.x.x.55             0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif1.0 --physdev-is-bridged

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

cat /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp | grep -e script

```
# (network-script network-bridge)
# (network-script 'network-bridge netdev=eth1')
# (network-script 'network-bridge bridge=<name>')
#(vif-script vif-bridge)
(network-script network-route)
(vif-script     vif-route)
#(network-script network-nat)
#(vif-script     vif-nat)
#(resource-label-change-script '')
```

Ping Dom0 -> DomU

```
PING x.x.x.55 (x.x.x.55) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from x.x.x.55: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
```

tcpdump -Kn | grep 55

```
21:01:36.545890 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4880, seq 4, length 64
21:01:36.551504 IP 8.8.8.8 > x.x.x.55: ICMP echo reply, id 4880, seq 4, length 64
21:01:37.545838 IP x.x.x.55 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4880, seq 5, length 64
21:01:37.550473 IP 8.8.8.8 > x.x.x.55: ICMP echo reply, id 4880, seq 5, length 64
```

## Question

What can it be that Dom0 does not forward the incoming TCP packages to my DomU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Well, as it turned out, all of the settings above are ***perfectly correct***. The problem was, that my hoster assigned a dedicated MAC adress to the additional IP. Therefore Dom0 discarded the package right away, because it thought, that it isn't a package for itself.

After removing this virtual MAC, the packages got accepted perfectly and routed through the whole system.

### Therefore

If you encounter strange package drops on your internet ethernet device (`eth0` in my case), make sure everything else if correct, and **make shure the MAC address is the same as of your main address, i.e. the one of `eth0`!**